Derivation of ward identity for broken scale symmetry
I am trying to compute zero energy theorems for scale symmetry, which is given as [1]:
$$
\begin{align}
&\int d^4 y ~ T^* \langle 0| \Delta(y) \phi(x_1) \ldots \phi(x_n)|0\rangle \nonumber\\
&= i T^* \langle 0| \delta\phi(x_1) \ldots \phi(x_n)|0\rangle \nonumber\\
&\quad +i T^* \langle 0| \phi(x_1)\delta\phi(x_2) \ldots \phi(x_n)|0\rangle \nonumber\\
& \quad + \ldots \tag{3.2.6}
\end{align}
$$
where the scale current is $s^\mu =x_\nu\theta^{\mu\nu}$, and $\partial_\mu s^\mu = \Delta.$ The transformation for field for scale transformation is given as $\delta \phi =  (d+x^\lambda \partial_\lambda) \phi$; where d is the scale dimension.
Now, if I compute the first term in right hand side of eqn. 3.2.6, then obtain
$$
\begin{align}
&T^* \langle 0|  (d+x_1^\lambda \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1^\lambda}) \phi(x_1) \ldots \phi(x_n)|0\rangle\\
&=  (d+x_1^\lambda \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1^\lambda})T \langle 0|  \phi(x_1) \ldots \phi(x_n)|0\rangle \tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
where I have used the property of $T^*-$product as given in [2]:
$$
T^*\langle 0| \partial_\mu\phi(x) \partial_\nu\phi(y)|0\rangle = \partial_\mu \partial_\nu T\langle 0| \phi(x) \phi(y)|0\rangle \tag{2.9}
$$
from eqs. 2, Fourier transform of eqn. 3.2.6 in momentum space I find,
$$
\begin{align}
i \left(nd-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} p_i \frac{\partial}{\partial p_i}\right) \Gamma^{(n)}(p_1,\ldots,p_n) = \Gamma^{(n)}_{\Delta}(0;p_1,\ldots,p_n)
\end{align} \tag{3}
$$
where $\Gamma^{(n)}(p_1,\ldots,p_n)$ is defined as,
$$
\begin{align}
(2\pi)^4 \delta^{(4)}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n p_i\right) \Gamma^{(n)}(p_1,\ldots,p_n) = \int d^4x_1 \ldots d^4 x_n \exp\left(i\sum_{j=1}^n p_j x_j\right) T \langle 0|  \phi(x_1) \ldots \phi(x_n)|0\rangle , \\
(2\pi)^4 \delta^{(4)}\left(k+\sum_{i=1}^n p_i\right) \Gamma^{(n)}_{\Delta}(k;p_1,\ldots,p_n) = \int d^4y d^4x_1 \ldots d^4 x_n \exp\left(ik y+i\sum_{j=1}^n p_j x_j\right) T \langle 0| \Delta(y) \phi(x_1) \ldots \phi(x_n)|0\rangle .
\end{align}
$$
But as derived in eqn. 3.3.2 page 79 of [1], has the following form,
$$
\begin{align}
i \left(nd+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} p_i \frac{\partial}{\partial p_i} -4\right) \Gamma^{(n)}(p_1,\ldots,p_n) = \Gamma^{(n)}_{\Delta}(0;p_1,\ldots,p_n)
\end{align} \tag{3.3.2}
$$
The reason for extra "-4" in the eqn. 3.3.4 on pg. 79 of [1] as "The factor four appears because in passing form the Fourier transform of a $T^*$-product to the conventionally defined $\Gamma^{(n)}$, we must factor out a four-dimensional $\delta$-function, which leaves the four behind as it passes through the differential operator"
can anyone explain the above statement. What does it mean by Fourier transform of $T^*$ -product?
[1] Chapter 3: Dilatations, Sidney Coleman's Aspect of symmetry.
[2] callan-coleman-jackiw, A new improved energy-momentum tensor (https://doi.org/10.1016/0003-4916(70)90394-5)

The four comes when you integrate $p^\mu \frac{\partial}{\partial p^\mu} F(p)$ by parts and drop a boundary term, then you get $-F(p) \frac{\partial p^\mu}{\partial p^\mu} = - 4 F(p)$.

Hi @Andrew. But there is no integration over $p$ to integrate.  sorry I did not understand clearly.

Yeah, so since delta functions, and derivatives of delta functions, are involved, this equation is going to be best understood as a distribution. So implicitly, the way to rigorously to define the equation will be to integrate against a test function, and integrate by parts to get rid of the derivative acting on the Dirac delta. I was trying to write up a more formal answer but wasn't 100% sure exactly what the starting point was, if I have time I'll try to come back to this later to explain this in more detail.
